# How to extract date fields from string/text field in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, clrstoredprocedure

There is a text filed in a table called as description. I would like to extract two date fields from this string when there is an occurrence of '~' character using sql server 2005 stored procedure. Help me out in this case.

Example: string: '长期租金;10/1/2012 ~ 10/31/2012'. At occurrence of ~ operator I would like to have from-date: 20121001 and to-date:20121031.

Comment: You need to be REALLY specific about the rules you need implementing. For example; `Everything from the first ';' to the next '~' is the start_date. Everything from that '~' to the next ';' (or end of string) is the end_date`. ***You*** need to establish the ***exact*** and ***guaranteed*** behaviour of that string. ***Then*** we can help you fullfil that requirement.

Comment: The only guaranteed stuff is the ~ operator and if it is present then to the left there will be a from-date and to the right there will be a to-date. If this operator is not present in the string, I will ignore it.

Comment: '长期租金;11/1/2012 ~ 10/31/2012', 
If we tries to extract a date from this, Which will lead confussion, because 2 possibilities,
(1)1/1/2012
(2)11/1/2012
As you said ~ is only guarrenty stuff

Comment: That's already an insuffient description.  Your example has characters before your date.  Is there a guarantee that...  If there is a `~' you should look left to the preceding ';' or to the start of the string if the ';' is not present?  Or is it possible that '~' can appear in some other text that has nothing to do with dates?  I'm sorry to be picky, but that's my point, you need to establish categorical rules to work with.  These rules may describe multiple scenarios that behvae differently, but they.you need to describe everything necessary to always be able to find that date for you.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance you can use the following but really you need an exists clause or something like that to test the string for the tilde (~) and as everyone else has stated, this only works if the string always has a semicolon(;) and a tilde(~). You can convert to the strings into datetime fields if you need.
I have placed the string in a variable to make it easier to read...

```
DECLARE @string AS NVARCHAR(255)

SET @string = '长期租金;10/1/2012 ~ 10/31/2012'

SELECT   StartDate = SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX(';',@string)+1,LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX('~',@string)-1)
        ,EndDate =  LTRIM(RIGHT(@string,LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX('~',@string)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method which will give the start and end dates. I left most of the testing selects in place but commented out.

```
DECLARE @string AS NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Seperator as char(1) = '~'
declare @CharStartDate as varchar(10)
declare @CharStopDate as varchar(10)
declare @StartDate as date
declare @StopDate as date

declare @I int

--SET @string = 'xvvvvvvcc;1/09/2012 ~ 1/10/2012xx'
--SET @string = 'xvvvvvvcc;12/31/2012 ~ 1/1/2012xx'
--SET @string = 'xvvvvvvcc;12/1/2012 ~ 10/0/2012xx'
SET @string = 'xvvvvvvcc;1/2/2012 ~ 1/3/2012xx'
--longest date 12/31/2011 = 10
--shortest date 1/1/2012 = 8
-- width of seperator = 3 

SELECT 
@CharStartDate = substring (@string, CHARINDEX(@Seperator,@string)-11,10)
,@CharStopDate = substring (@string, CHARINDEX(@Seperator,@string)+2,10)

--SELECT  @CharStartDate,@CharStopDate

select @I = ascii(substring(@CharStartDate,1,1))
While @I > 57
BEGIN
set @CharStartDate = substring(@CharStartDate,2,10)
--select @CharStartDate
select @I = ascii(substring(@CharStartDate,1,1))
END

select @I = ascii(substring(REVERSE(@CharStopDate),1,1))
While @I > 57
BEGIN
set @CharStopDate = REVERSE(substring(REVERSE(@CharStopDate),2,10))
--select @CharStopDate
select @I = ascii(substring(REVERSE(@CharStopDate),1,1))
END

--select ascii(';'),ascii('9'),ascii('8'),ascii('7'),ascii('6'),ascii('6'),ascii('4'),ascii('3'),ascii('2'),ascii('1'),ascii('0')
SELECT  @StartDate = @CharStartDate,@StopDate = @CharStopDate
--SELECT  @I,@string,@Seperator,@CharStartDate,@CharStopDate,@StartDate,@StopDate
select datediff(dd,@StartDate,@StopDate) AS 'DateDiff',@StartDate as 'Start Date',@StopDate as 'Stop Date'
```

I will leave it to you to check for the seperator.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@Temp nvarchar(max))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  WHILE PatIndex ('%[^0-9~/]%', @Temp) > 0
  SET @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^0-9~/]%', @Temp), 1, '')
  RETURN @Temp
END

DECLARE @string nvarchar(max) = '长期租金;10/1/2012 ~ 10/31/2012'
SELECT CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING([dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@string), 0,
       CHARINDEX('~', [dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@string))), 101) AS BDate,
       CONVERT(date, SUBSTRING([dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@string),
       CHARINDEX('~', [dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@string)) + 1,
       CHARINDEX('~', REVERSE([dbo].[RemoveAlphaCharacters](@string)))), 101) AS EDate
```

Answer (score -2):

i have never used the older version of SQL cause i just graduated but doesnt it have the EXTRACT() function?.. The syntax goes like this below.

```
SELECT First_Name ,    
  
    EXTRACT ( CAST(Created_date AS DATE) FROM Created_date ) AS Date_only ;
```

You specify 'First_name' to let SQL know you want it as a column and 'created_date' is the field from which youre trying to separate the date. the cast function converts your field to DATE value before extractig it.

i hope this helps . thank you. if im wrong please let me know i would like to improve myself.

Comment: EXTRACT is not a T-SQL function. You're answering the wrong question.